# .env file is not being ignored in github on a node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a .gitignore file and added
node_modules and  .env on it .
node modules file is being ignored but .env file in not being ignored in github.

Comment: What does the content of your .gitignore look like?

Comment: Have you created the .gitignore file after committing the .env file?

Comment: If you can see the file in GitHub, that means that you have already committed it.